# Is it possible to run the command line flag "chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required" with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, command-line, policy, autoplay

I am trying to avoid getting the following error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`. After taking a look at the Chrome autoplay policy on this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/), I have found out that the solution would be using this command line flag `chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required`. However, I need to run it using a JavaScript code.

Here is my relevant code:

```
const audio = new Audio('{{ asset('sounds/notification.mp3') }}');
audio.play();
```

So, my question is: Is that doable with JavaScript? If yes, how?

Comment: Why do you need to run it from JS? It's a shell command so just run it in whatever command line interface your OS has.

Comment: @Lennholm: Good question! In fact, I'm developing a website where users get notified with ringtones. So, if user's browse follows the Chrome autoplay policy, that would cause a problem since the required command line flag wouldn't be already run on it. Hence, I've thought that the best solution would be to run it with JavaScript. You see what I mean?

Comment: Eh, OK. So you're actually talking about running it on a user's computer? Well no, you can't run shell commands on a user's device through the JS on your web page, that would be a pretty disastrous security hole. The autoplay policy is there for a reason and if there were an intentional way for a web site to circumvent it on a visitor's browser, it would be completely undermined. You just have to hope that your users like your site enough to get its media engagement index up or manually whitelist it for autoplay. Develop it to degrade gracefully if autoplay fails.